# What object persister should I use for POJOs?

Tags: pojo, robospice, object-persistence

I know that `RoboSpice` provides some built-in `ObjectPersisters`. Can I use one of them or should I write my own to cache lightweight POJOs?

I tried using the built-in ones, but I got an `Exception` that the class I was trying to cache couldn't be handled by any persister, which, I suppose, is due to the fact that the built-in persisters don't know anything about the class that I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you use RS, you use persisters that rely on the same technology that is used for parsing.

For instance, if you use one of the pre-set RS services for SpringAndroid, Retrofit, etc. You will end up with persisters that work out-of-the box and persist data in the same way/format as they are read from network.

That is one of the great advantage of RS : persistence &caching is free in most cases.